# Google glass app freezes once the app is invoked after the device goes to sleep mode

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

The app consists of a low frequency card that updates the latitude longitude and speed, on tap it takes you to an activity in which an image is displayed. On tap of the image, the image is processed and voice output is given to the user. The app works perfectly fine. But after the device enters sleep mode and the app is invoked again, the low frequency live card doesn't update and on tap, the image from project folder is not displayed.Later the app freezes the device. Why is the app not killed by the OS? I am running `XE 20.3`

Here is my log

```
11-27 14:44:43.576: E/GmsClient(936): unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.droidguard.service.START
11-27 14:44:44.474: E/VoiceTriggers(829): Unable to build voice trigger for service ResolveInfo{41e6c980 com.glob3mobile.glasses/.G3MGlassesDemoService m=0x108000}; com.google.android.glass.app.VoiceTriggerBuildingException: Custom voice triggers not allowed for com.glob3mobile.glasses
11-27 14:44:44.553: E/GCoreFlp(1196): Bound FusedProviderService with LocationManager
11-27 14:44:55.857: E/GCoreFlp(1196): Bound FusedProviderService with LocationManager
11-27 14:45:05.138: E/WindowManager(495): Starting window AppWindowToken{41ffb180 token=Token{41fcf978 ActivityRecord{41ff7120 u0 com.example.lowfreq/com.example.viva.inputImage t2}}} timed out
11-27 14:45:33.888: E/btif_sock_rfcomm(898): find_rfc_slot_by_id unable to find RFCOMM slot id: 368
11-27 14:45:39.037: E/btif_sock_rfcomm(898): find_rfc_slot_by_id unable to find RFCOMM slot id: 369
11-27 14:45:44.177: E/btif_sock_rfcomm(898): find_rfc_slot_by_id unable to find RFCOMM slot id: 370
```

I have set up life cycle events for the live card.

Comment: Do you mind showing your `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods?